# Python Pandas: Create New Column With Calculations Based on Categorical Values in A Different Column

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, where-clause, calculation

I have the following sample data frame:

```
id  category        time
43  S               8
22  I               10
15  T               350
18  L               46
```

I want to apply the following logic:

1) if category value equals "T" then create new column called "time_2" where "time" value is divided by 24.

2) if category value equals "L" then create new column called "time_2" where "time" value is divided by 3.5.

3) otherwise take existing "time" value from categories S or I

Below is my desired output table:

```
    id  category        time    time_2
    43  S               8       8
    22  I               10      10
    15  T               350     14.58333333
    18  L               46      13.14285714
```

I've tried using pd.np.where to get the above to work but am confused around syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` for rules

```
In [1066]: df['time_2'] = df.time / df.category.map({'T': 24, 'L': 3.5}).fillna(1)

In [1067]: df
Out[1067]:
   id category  time     time_2
0  43        S     8   8.000000
1  22        I    10  10.000000
2  15        T   350  14.583333
3  18        L    46  13.142857
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). This is a good alternative to nested `np.where` logic.

```
conditions = [df['category'] == 'T', df['category'] == 'L']
values = [df['time'] / 24, df['time'] / 3.5]

df['time_2'] = np.select(conditions, values, df['time'])

print(df)

   id category  time     time_2
0  43        S     8   8.000000
1  22        I    10  10.000000
2  15        T   350  14.583333
3  18        L    46  13.142857
```